# Taxonomy term missing as type of data to store in new field for content type

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I have Drupal 6.2. I added a taxonomy term and I am trying to to add it as a new field to a content type. However, I don't see "taxonomy term" as a "type of data to store" when I try to select a field type.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Content taxonomy](http://drupal.org/project/content_taxonomy) module. It provides a CCK field type for referencing taxonomy terms.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the Taxonomy administrative page (admin/content/taxonomy), and click on the "edit vocabulary" link for the vocabulary you want to associate with a content type.

[image: screenshot]

On that page, you find the "Content types" field set that allows you to associate the content type for which a vocabulary should be used.

[image: screenshot]